Runway edge and center line lights spacing
We use the number of visible lights on a runway edge/center line to estimate the RVR in LVTOs. So, what is the minimum/maximum spacing between runway edge and center line spacing ?
Where do we find this information if published on Jeppessen charts ?
If possible to have more details about such standards.

This is better than what I would have answered.  https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/regulations/what-to-know-about-runway-lighting-space-and-color-configuration-explained/

Thank you for your contribution, I've read that article but it doesn't mention if those spacing are published on Jeppessen charts.

You don't actually mean to ask for the spacing "between runway edge and center line," the runway half-width, right?

@CamilleGoudeseune -- as far as I can tell, that is what he or she is asking about

I am actually asking about the spacing between each light bulb on the runway centerline and edges

The FAA AIM 2-1-5 says:

Runway centerline lights ... are spaced at 50-foot intervals.

(The previous section, 2-1-4, describes runway edge lights, but mentions nothing about their spacing.)
Figure 3 of the FAA's AC 150/5340-30D and page 4 of AC 150/5340-30H say that runway edge lights are at most 200 feet apart, and uniformly spaced except for intersections.  No minimum spacing is specified.

Only some of the examples I found of Jeppesen charts with an "Additional Runway Information" section mentioned lighting therein;  none mentioned the spacing of edge lights.
Jeppesen might not even ask airports for that detail.  If you need to know that for just a few airports instead of thousands, either ask the airports yourself, or look at aerial photos.  For the airports near me, for instance, a few seconds' zooming and squinting in Google Maps showed me that C16 Frasca Field's are about 180 feet apart, KTIP Rantoul 200 feet, KCMI Champaign 200 feet.
Maybe only tiny airports like Frasca have spacing closer the mandated 200 feet, just to minimize the cost of purchase and maintenance.  If so, that's another reason Jeppesen would exclude that from its charts.

Thank you for the detailed articles, they answer 90% of my question. Do you know if the information about the spacing is published on Jeppessen charts ?
